# "enablePrettyUrl" dont work with standard docker-compose configuration

Tags: docker-compose, yii2

I have installed yii2 advanced template. It contains `docker-compose.yml` file after installation.

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - 20080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  backend:
    build: backend
    ports:
      - 21080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret

  #pgsql:
  #  image: postgres:9.5
  #  environment:
  #    - POSTGRES_DB=yii2advanced
  #    - POSTGRES_USER=yii2advanced
  #    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
```

I don't change it and just run `docker-compose up -d`. I don't want to install Apache/nginx and so on. I see that this file gives me an ability to up all in docker and I'm going to use it.

So, all works nice, but I see ugly URls in my application. Something like `http://localhost:21080/index.php?r=site%2Flogin`. It looks like terrible. I know about `urlManager`, I'm trying to switch on it:

`config/main.php`

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

But now all routes give me 404. Is there some simple way to get started with Yii2 with nice URLs and without installing apache/nginx, creating virtual hosts, creating .htaccess and so on? Can I just make `docker-compose up -d` and have pretty URLs?

Comment: In you case is not problem with `yii` framework is a miss configuration of apache. You must add `.htaccess` file to you `web` folders with rewrite rules for pretty URLs. This file is not present by default in git repository, so you must add it by your self.

Comment: @ustmaestro yes, thank you. I already solved by adding .htaccess. But it's a few uncomfortable to think about `.htaccess`, `apache` and so on. It would be better just start working without some additional activity (like we are working with laravel)

Comment: You may open an issue on github, but I think there was already one https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/98

Comment: @ustmaestro maybe. I hope it will not exist for Yii3. Using apache in 2020 (does not matter if we are talking about development on a local machine) is strange. Nginx, as it seems to me, is standard for modern php stack.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution worked for me.

Add `.htaccess` in `frontend/web` and `backend/web` folders

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```